# Portable Class Library equivalent to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod

Tags: .net, system.reflection, portable-class-library

s there Portable Class Library equivalent to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod?

I'm new to PCLs.  I'm justing looking into whether I can use a PCL to hold some client code that will definitely be used on Silverlight and may be used elsewhere.  Having scanned the source, I can see plenty of calls to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod which doesn't seem to exist in the PCL.

** EDIT **

I've ripped this sample out of the library in question.  IsNullOrEmpty() was using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) which doesn't seem to be available, so that bit's a fudge.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LinqToLdap.PCL
{
    public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        internal static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this String str)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
        }

        public static IQueryable<TSource> FilterWith<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string filter)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            if (filter.IsNullOrEmpty()) throw new Exception("Filters cannot be null, empty, or white-space.");

            if (!filter.StartsWith("("))
            {
                filter = "(" + filter + ")";
            }

            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
                        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TSource) }),
                    new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Constant(filter) }
                    )
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Devices that require the PCL won't appear until summer 2013.  Maybe enough time to figure out how to give up on methods that are not supported?  GetCurrentMethod() certainly shouldn't be a critical omission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I 'own' the Portable Library project at Microsoft)

We don't expose it in PCL because it's not supported in Windows 8 .NET for Metro apps. What's your usage of this method?

Comment: I've updated the original question to include a sample.  There are many similar extension methods in the original library.

Comment: Hi David... I was looking at using the GetCurrentMethod purely for adding to debug logging, much like the C _ _FUNCTION_ _ macro. Is there some other way to achieve this in PCL .NET?

Comment: It's a bummer that this method is missing. This was a critical for logging inputs to a shared library. Knowing the current method allows you to ensure that your logging code is logging all input parameters. Very important when method signatures change.

Comment: Now that the usage of windows mobile as a whole has plummeted to a mere 0.4% and Windows 8 is an ever decreasing share of this already tiny user base, perhaps we could think to add this into the Portable Libraries now?