# Get current method's MethodInfo in portable assembly

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I'd like to get current executing method info in portable assembly with Windows Phone and Windows Store apps support.
However, `MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()` and `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` are not available in such a portable assembly.
How can I get a MethodInfo for current method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to use [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) (has other overloads too)?

Comment: I am porting a library to portable implementation. That library has a number of methods that acquire itself's MethodInfo.
I can use `Type.GetMethod()` as a workaround, but it would require several dozens of calls like `typeof(FooClass).GetMethod("BarMethod")`. 
In my opinion it is a bad style (AKA stringly typed code).

Comment: @konstantin.zaikin I agree. But I don't think there's another way. Here's another question about the same method: [Portable Class Library equivalent to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657744/)

Comment: Thank you, looks like it is missing as it is not present in Windows Store apps